# Aggregated Results

Tags: apex, soql

I'm getting Aggregate Results error when I turn my SOQL statement into an aggregate to get the newest record created when there is a duplicate record.  How can I resolve this?

```
Map<String,Business__c> pMap = New Map<String, Business__c>();

for(Business__c e : [
    SELECT Max(Id), Combine__c FROM Business__c
    WHERE CreatedDate = Today Group by Combine__c
])
{
    pMap.put(e.Combine__c,e);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you receive?

Comment: There is a typo in the in "Group By" but the error is: Error: Compile Error: Loop variable must be an SObject or list of AggregateResult at line 13 column 25

Comment: See the Apex dev guide doc -- you need to iterate over an `AggregateResult`, not a `Business__c`

Comment: I dont know if i am wrong, but applying MAX function on id may not work as it is an alpha numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate functions in SOQL return AggregateResult as object, so your code should be something like this -

```
Map<String,Business__c> pMap = New Map<String, Business__c>();

for(AggregateResult result : [
    SELECT Max(Id) maxi, Combine__c comb FROM Business__c
    WHERE CreatedDate = Today Group by Combine__c
])
{
    pMap.put((String)result.get(comb), someyourobjectvalue);
}
```

This is not a working code but just to give you an idea. Also are you sure that your map pair should be string,business__c> and not Id,business__c> ?